# Cannot resolve JvmTypeReference

Tags: xtext, eclipse-emf, xbase

I am using XText to create a DSL that works with Java classes. I have created a metamodel that includes a JvmTypeReference to an existing Java class (I am only interested in classes,  but I have tried JvmType and JvmGenericType, to no avail). In the validator (whose supertype is XbaseValidator) I can resolve these references to LightweightTypeReferences and then access their attributes that way (supertype, qualifiedName, etc). However, at no other point in the code can I do the same, i.e. resolve JvmTypeReference to a useful resource, because I have no access to the XbaseValidator methods.

What is the intended way of using JvmTypeReferences anywhere other than in a subclass of XbaseValidator?

Comment: Did you check the other examples that come with Xtext or the https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/201_sevenlang_introduction.html ?

Comment: Yes, and most of them are about the inverse process (i.e. mapping own entities to Jvm types).